# How to increase the size of window-buttons on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: themes, configuration, 19.04, window-buttons

I would like to know, How do you get windows-buttons [windows-buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHutm.png)(minimize, maximize and close) a lot bigger. I have try some tweak to make the bar thinner (doing the opposite), but without any success.
I also tried to change the "Legacy Window Titles" to a bigger size, but it only change the letter size.

I use the Mojave-Dark theme with Yaru icons.

[My system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnOOb.png)

Thank you,

**EDIT**
I did what other forum talked about. But I end up to a wall. Still unable to change the size. I see Yaru theme is similar, but with bigger corner buttons. Can I change the button layout on a theme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize the window control buttons (close, restore, maximize)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267360/resize-the-window-control-buttons-close-restore-maximize)

Comment: I didn't see this one. I've tried what they said, but I don't figured out where is the "Buttons size"...

Answer (score 0):

I guess resizing Windows buttons are **not possible** in this theme.

Alternatively, you can change the DPI settings of the display allows you to effectively **zoom** the entire screen. But not recommended!

Comment: i think I have to live with that... or maybe find a way to change corner buttons...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.css` file that describe the window button style to override the system default style, do not forget to re-login.

Create `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and put some style in it, here I show the basic syntax

```
button.titlebutton {
min-height: 30px;
min-width: 50px;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Because all window buttons (minimize, maximize, close) inherit from `button.titlebutton`, this definition will override the default definition of `titlebutton` style.

This can increase the size of your window buttons. However, I wanted to achieve the same window button style as that in `windows 10`: the window buttons extends to the edge of screen, but I failed to do so, because if I write `margin: 0`, there is still gap among window buttons and between window button and screen edge. I saw a method of setting `margin` to be negative, but it is not a good way. If you figure out some methods to achieve `windows 10`-like effect, please let me know. May it help.

Comment: If you don't like negative margins, could you try with a `position: relative; top: <some>px; left: <some>px;` combo? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp (On this page, look for the "Try it yourself" button for an interactive sample.)

Comment: @Levente It does not work, because `gtk` does not achieve a full implementation of `css` syntax. So some keywords may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to imitate Windows's click targets (full height of the window titlebar and no extra space on the right of the close button) with some `gtk.css` styles.

1. Create a file named `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.
2. Enter this CSS code, which removes the space to the right of the close button and makes the buttons fill the height of the window titlebar.

   ```css
   headerbar {
     padding-right: 0;
   }

   .titlebutton {
     min-width: 44px;
     min-height: 44px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Save the file, then log out and back in to apply the changes.

This won't visually appear the same as Windows, but it gives the buttons some much-needed usability improvement.

Note that this won't affect programs that set their own window titlebar styling -- Firefox, for example.